# Blender suddenly crashing Desktop Environment

Tags: linux

I have used Blender for atleast a year now, and suddenly certain normal actions are causing blender to crash my Window Manager entirely. Actions that are causing this include importing textures, and certain actions in rendered view like looking around in rendered view. I have not had this issue at all before, <strike>and I am having a similar issue with UPBGE</strike>. I am running the latest version of Blender on Steam on ArchLinux, my Desktop Environment is XFCE4, Display Manager is LightDM, and I have a Nvidia 960M GPU.

EDIT: I decided to download blender 2.80 from blender.org, and it is working perfectly fine with no issues, so the issue must be with 2.83.

Comment: Does that happen with the version from blender.org?

Comment: If it suddenly started crashing, but worked properly before, then the question is what has been changed on your system? Were you using the same version of Blender before? Have you checked that the GPU is working correctly and is using a recent graphics driver?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall blender and enable extensions one by one till it starts to crash again.

Comment: I have already installed 2.83 from blender.org, and it also has the same issue. I tried to verify files on steam, and it found 174 invalid files, but even after it fixed that the issue persisted.